# No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' while importing tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

While I was importing tflearn I'm getting this error:-

**import tflearn**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/rohansethi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/**init**.py", line 4, in 
    from . import config
  File "/Users/rohansethi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in 
    from .variables import variable
  File "/Users/rohansethi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in 
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'**

Comment: which tf version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an older version of TensorFlow.

```
tensorflow.contrib
```

Was removed from tensorflow with versions >=1.14.

This is what you can do:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

To check if everything is working fine:
Start python in the console by typing `python` Then:

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
```

It should show you 1.14.
Now you can run your program.

Comment: issue fixed. But got another issue. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.eager'. Can you help?