# no module named tensorflow.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this problem when I import tensorflow.contrib.slim

```
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
```

i get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/toshiba/PFE/DocFace-master/src/tflib.py", line 28, in <module>
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

tensorflow is correctly installed and i found some solutions that said that the file name is tensorflow so it causes the problem but that is not the case in here

Comment: Is tensorflow in PATH?

Comment: Downgrade to TF 1.15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' while importing tflearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347171/no-module-named-tensorflow-contrib-while-importing-tflearn)

Comment: @GPhilo no it did not i tried it.

Comment: What is the output of running `print(tf.__version__)`?

Comment: @GPhilo >>> 2.1.0

Comment: I just tried to uninstall tensorflow and reinstall it and it worked somehow. Thank you

Comment: So, you have TF 2.1.0 installed. Uninstall aything TF-related in your environment, then reinstall version 1.15. Just like it says in the duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading tf.contrib.slim manually to tf 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628439/upgrading-tf-contrib-slim-manually-to-tf-2-0)

Answer (score 13):

You probably have TensorFlow version 2.* installed, but [`tf.contrib.slim`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/slim) is TensorFlow 1.15 code. You can check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_note_on_slim_contriblayers) how to migrate your existing code to tensorflow 2.*.

If you instead want to keep your code, you can downgrade to TensorFlow by typing `pip install tensorflow==1.15` into your command-line to downgrade to TensorFlow 1.15.

Comment: Thank you, i'll keep this in mind just in case it happened again.

Comment: I have `tensorflow=1.15.5+nv22.4` but the program still can't find `tf.contrib`

Comment: Then there may be something wrong with how you import the tensorflow module, because [the version you mention](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.15.5%2Bnv22.04) does include `tensorflow.contrib`.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib` is not supported in TensorFlow 2.x, but you can exploit [TensorFlow-Slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim) avoiding to downgrade TensorFlow.

You have to install TensforFlow-Slim as `pip install --upgrade tf_slim` and then substitute `import tensorflow.contrib.slim` as slim in your code with `import tf_slim as slim`